# Monitor App Utilisation

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, app-store, viewwillappear

Is there any way to track iPhone app utilisation? I'd like to know every time a user has opened or interacted with my app. I don't want any other information about the user or their device. I don't even need to identify the user. I just want to monitor frequency of use and inactivity.

I thought of possibly creating a unique ID using time in seconds and then writing some code in viewWillAppear that sends an email containing the unique ID. But I don't even know if my App will be approved for sale in the AppStore with this function.

Any suggestions would be welcome - thanks you very much in advance for any effort spent on answering this question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just use [Flurry](http://www.flurry.com/) in you App

Flurry Analytics delivers powerful insight into how consumers interact with your mobile applications in real-time. Over 60,000 companies have chosen Flurry Analytics to use in more than 150,000 applications across iOS, Android, Blackberry, Windows Phone, JavaME and HTML5.

Flurry Analytics helps mobile application developers make better apps, deepen consumer engagement and improve monetization of their applications. The service is free, cross-platform, easy to integrate, able to handle data loads of any size application and frequently updated with new, advanced features.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google Analytics to track these figures.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/